# Getting X,Y coordinates/position of slider

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I need to get the [X,Y] positions of a slider.
I already tried the function "PointFromScreen" but I didn't get any result.

Anyone?

Thanks

```
    private void SliderPosition(object sender)
    {
        Slider slider = (Slider)sender;
        int x = (int)slider.Value;
        Point x1 = Point.Parse(x);
        Point slider_point = slider.PointFromScreen(x1);
    }
```

Comment: How can we help without seeing your code ?

Comment: You should post some code to show the context of your problem. It's a little confusing.

Comment: already updated! thanks for the tip

Comment: @user2205242 do you have any `Canvas`? The Position is calculable only if your `Slider` is placed on a `Canvas` (not sure, because I'm also a WPF newbie :)

Comment: Slider in top of a Canvas? No..

Comment: @user2205242 yes, you should try that. BTW, you should also talk a little on why you want to get the position of your Slider so that we can find a more straight way to solve your actual problem (of course without finding the position).

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE and more clear doubt:

I have a video going through, and a slide that is dependent of the number of frames.
Video format is 640x480, slider is defined in terms of frames!

I need to know, when the right button is pushed in the video image, the position[X,Y] of the slider so that I can draw a line in a Canvas that is beneath the video.

I think it's clear now. Going through the library, the only parameter I can find is the slider.value but that doesn't make my case.

Source code of my try:

```
     private void Slider_position(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Slider e,    System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e1)
    {
        if (e1.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            Line line = new Line();
            line.X1 = e. //something, i would get here the coordinates X,Y of slider here
            // calculation from slider position to canvas position
            // draw a line of the height of the canvas here after

        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using MouseClick() as this will give you the mouse positions, from the The AutoIt Window Info.

Comment: Amealy,thanks for your answer. I cant do that because I really need the slider position to perform a relationship between the frame number of an image and the slider coordinates. :/

Comment: Try u sing Opt("MouseCoordMode", 0) in the options ->Coord Mode you cahnge what mouse coords the info tool gives you. Does that help?

Comment: I have tryed it and it doesnt work.. I did plenty research in msdn and it seems that there isnt still a method to retrieve the [x,y] position of the slider, only the value. But since my slider value depends on the number of frames, i cannot use it. I really need to find a way to get the X,Y position of the slider in XAML grid regardless of the number of frames